# Bash script for interactive ssh and mysql commands

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, ssh

I'm studying MySQL, and every time I have to

1. Enter `ssh XXX@XXX` command, and enter my password to the school server.
2. Enter `mysql -u XXX -p` command, and enter MySQL password.

I want to create a Bash script for performing the steps above automatically.

I can accomplish the first step with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f    
set address xxx.com   
set password xxx  
set timeout 10   
spawn ssh xxx@$address   
expect {    "*yes/no" { send "yes\r"; exp_continue}    "*password:" { send "$password\r" }  }  
send clear\r 
interact
```

But I don't know how to automatically input the next command (`mysql -u xxx -p`) and the password.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need such a complex script to just enter the MySQL console on remote machine. Use the features of the `ssh` tool:

```
ssh -tt user@host -- mysql -uuser -ppassword
```

The `-t` option forces pseudo-terminal allocation. Multiple `-t` force tty allocation, even if `ssh` has no local tty (see `man ssh`). Note the use of `-p` option. There must be no spaces between `-p` and password (see the manual for `mysql`).

Or even connect via `mysql` directly, if the MySQL host is accessible from your local machine:

```
mysql -hhost -uuser -p
```

Don't forget to adjust the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)):

```
#!/bin/bash -
```

Comment: What if I want to create a bash file for running these steps, I mean I just open the file, than all the commands will be correctly input in terminal.

Comment: @J.Pei, you can put the command into a file, of course. Don't forget to adjust the she-bang line accordingly.

Comment: So, the effectiveness of "-tt" is combine the 2 commands(ssh ... and mysql ...) to one command line?@Ruslan Osmanov

Comment: @J.Pei, no, `-tt` forces pseudo-terminal allocation. And you need a pseudo-terminal for interactive session. Otherwise, the session may stall waiting for input, or even fail.

Answer (score -1):

Use my.cnf to store your password securly like ssh keys.

https://easyengine.io/tutorials/mysql/mycnf-preference/

Same way ssh is also possible through ssh -i parameter and passing the private key path of the remote host.

Best of luck!